# Selenium with C# and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

In our project we are trying to figure out which approach would be better for testing from the below
1. Selenium with C#
2. Selenium with Java Script

I am able to find that C# require Selenium libraries and NUnit framework. However, is it possible to use MS Test instead of NUnit framework? We are using Visual Studio 2013.

Secondly, for JavaScript, I found that we need Standalone server to be run to execute the scripts. Is there any good framework available to implement selenium using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with javascript why not use Java with Eclispe and TestNG. This would not require a standalone server implementation to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the NUnit framework to be just a tool. You have lots of options with regards to C#: Xunit, Nunit, MSTest... Selenium is awesome. The question is more C# vs Javascript and which is better suited to your company.  I worked at a place where everyone used C#, so naturally using C# for testing meant a lot of external support. You can also call Javascript code in C# if needed via Selenium. I do this in a few rare instances. For Javascript, you have specflow, protractor, and Jasmine which work well together.